# Laravel combined where clause

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to fetch all users which have one role or another. I have tried like this and it doesn't work:

```
$dentist = Role::where('name', 'dentist')->orWhere('name', 'local_admin')->first()->users()->where('clinic_id', $user->clinic_id)->get();

$dentist = Role::where('name', ['dentist', 'local_admin')->first()->users()->where('clinic_id', $user->clinic_id)->get();

$dentist = Role::whereIn('name', ['dentist', 'local_admin')->first()->users()->where('clinic_id', $user->clinic_id)->get();
```

Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: Do you have missed a closing square bracket for third and fourth line of codes?

Answer (score 0):

You have to [define the relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) `Role` hasMany `users` then you can access `users` with [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$dentist = Role::with(['users' => function($query){
    $query->where('clinic_id', $user->clinic_id);
  })])
  ->where('name', 'dentist')
  ->orWhere('name', 'local_admin')
  ->first();
```

This would go in you Role model

```
/**
 * Get the users for the role.
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

This would go in your User model

```
/**
 * Get the role the user.
 */
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```